# Alternative to UploadFileControl.SaveAs(fileName)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload

Is there another method I can use, to obtain the "bytes Written" or something similar during uploading the file? I want a progress on it that is an actual progress for the data written, or is this not possible using this class and method? If not, what is a route to look into?

Thanks.

Basic Example:

```
if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
  savePath += FileUplaod1.FileName;
  FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath); ///  Here is where I want to do a stream or some way to grab
   //bytes written so I can do an async on it and show the progress, not wait until it is copleted, and then show a label status of "completed". Doing this for a form that has to be non-html5 compatibale. That is why I am not using a different method.  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files["userfile"];
            file.ContentLength;

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Was up so late last night, completely overlooked this one.

```
bytes[] filebytes = UplaodFile1.FileBytes ;
//Now I can send to stream.....
```